# UMP test for $H_0:p=0.5$ vs $H_1:p\neq0.5$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, statistical-power, neyman-pearson-lemma

Let $X_1,\dots, X_n$ Bernoulli trials. I know that the UMP tests for
 $$H_0:p=0.5 \quad\text{vs}\quad H_1:p>0.5$$
and
 $$H_0:p=0.5 \quad\text{vs}\quad H_1:p<0.5$$
can be obtained with the Neyman Pearson lemma to construct the test that rejects H_0, based on the test statistic $T = X_1+\dots+X_n$. However, I do not know how can I find the UMP test for
 $$H_0:p=0.5 \quad\text{vs}\quad H_1:p\neq0.5$$
I would appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: Using the generalized Neyman-Pearson lemma.

Comment: Why do you think the UMP test exists?